# Using Wireshark, how can I report DNS queries?

Tags: dns, wireshark

I start a capture with no other applications running on my machine other than chrome and Wireshark, and then I start a capture with Wireshark. And go to a website for about 20 seconds. How can I look at the DNS queries all sent in the capture time?

So for any given website, I need to find the

1. DNS resolved ip address
2. DNS server ip (I believe this is the destination ip)
3. DNS server port

Comment: It depends. If you use a recent Firefox and its default configuration it will use DoH to CloudFlare public resolvers and hence on the network you will see only HTTPS traffic and certainly not the DNS exchanges. This is by design. You are offtopic here as it is not related to programming (try [sf] instead or [su]) and not explaining clearly your setup/constraints. Another way to do it is to install a recursive nameserver you control and configure your  systems to use it. THen the nameserver logfile will tell you everything....

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the word `dns` in the filter field... simple as that

see more [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters)

Comment: If the browser uses DOH or DOT, that will not work.